# Is the HTML 5 Spec already complete?

Tags: html, standards, specifications

I'm was looking for an HTML 5 and CSS 3 framework, I found [52Framework](http://52framework.com/) but I've noticed that a lot of HTML 5 elements are still missing, even at the most basic level (`reset.css`).

I though of making my own framework but I need to know if the HTML 5 standard is already complete or if it's still subject to changes, I Googled a bit but couldn't find any clear answer.

Does anyone know? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first sentence of the [first page from google](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) has your answer.

Comment: I found a great synopsis of the history of HTML and the current state of HTML 5 at http://diveintohtml5.org/.  I think the author does a great job covering how proposed features end up in the final spec (vs. features in draft specs that are never implemented).

Comment: @Mayo: Yeah, it is really something.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: I understand HTML is still in development, maybe I should have rephrased my question a little better - what I wanted to know is if we can "count" on the new tags / attributes, i.e. is there a chance the `input type="email"` will be dropped somewhere along the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can still use aspects of it. See [When will HTML5 be finished?](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_HTML5_be_finished.3F) for details.

According to this WHATWG FAQ:

> "Finished" is a big deal... You'll be
>   able to use HTML5 long before then.
>   See [When will we be able to start
>   using these new features?](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_we_be_able_to_start_using_these_new_features.3F)
>
> It is estimated by the editor that
>   HTML5 will reach the W3C Candidate
>   Recommendation stage during 2012. That
>   doesn't mean you can't start using it
>   yet, though. Different parts of the
>   specification are at different
>   maturity levels. Some sections are
>   already relatively stable and there
>   are implementations that are already
>   quite close to completion, and those
>   features can be used today (e.g.
>   <canvas>). But other sections are
>   still being actively worked on and
>   changed regularly, or not even written
>   yet.

Comment: Yup — I forget where I read it, but I think Ian Hickson has talked about moving away from describing HTML as a versioned language, and towards thinking about individual modules.

Comment: @Paul. I remember the same thing, but couldn't find the link.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft – Thank you for the edit. Did not realize <canvas> had dropped of in the copy and paste.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5), it's still a **working draft** as of last month, so there can and will be changes to the spec as it develops. I'm guessing many of the elements that we know and use right now are here to stay though :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say its still work in progress.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Here are Ian Hickson’s estimates/guesses on when the HTML5 spec will be “complete”:

2012 - W3C Candidate Recommendation

2022 - W3C Recommendation (but see http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_HTML5_be_finished.3F for the tough criteria required for HTML5 to become a recommendation.)

Comment: @Alix - Unlikely. According to that schedule ( http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/programming-and-development/?p=718) it should have been in Last Call Working Draft state 9 months ago. It's currently nowhere near ready for last call. It'll probably be much later than those dates. Fortunately, those dates are largely irrelevant.

Comment: @Alix — HTML5 will become a W3C Recommendation when there are “two 100% complete and fully interoperable implementations” (see http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#When_will_HTML5_be_finished.3F). No-one knows when that will be; 2022 is an offhand guess. I don’t think HTML4 passes that test yet, and people seem to be using it quite happily.